# RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes() returns all zeros

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rngcryptoserviceprovider

I'm using the following code to generate an encryption salt.

```
TripleDES tripleDES = TripleDES.Create()
tripleDES.IV = new byte[8];

using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rngProvider.GetBytes(tripleDES.IV);
}

Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, tripleDES.IV);
tripleDES.Key = keyBytes.GetBytes(16);
```

But after calling `GetBytes()`, I can see that `tripleDES.IV` contains all zeros.

That certainly doesn't seem as random as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the source for `SymmetricAlgorithm`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/symmetricalgorithm.cs) (the base class for `TripleDES`), the `IV` property returns a clone of the current IV byte array, so `rngProvider.GetBytes()` is setting the bytes on a clone array, not the actual one.

You don't need to set the IV to a random value anyway - it will be initialized to one already after calling `TripleDES.Create()`. And if you want a new one for some reason, you can just call `GenerateIV()` which will set `IV` to a new random value.

Comment: Did you read the source code I linked? Look at the `IV` property

Comment: What nollidge is saying is that if you use `tripleDES.IV` the way you've specified, you are using the **getter** of the property, not the setter. That getter makes a copy and returns that as value. This copy is then randomized by you, and then garbage collected right after that. If you want to set the property manually, then you need to create a byte array, randomize it and then **assign it** to the property. That way the setter is used. But as nollidge mentions, that is hardly necessary because the IV will be randomized by default - for this specific part of the .NET framework anyway.

Comment: I.e. first encrypt, and then get the IV, it should be randomized.